# Converting prototype cells in a storyboard to .xib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a prototype cell in a Storyboard. Is there any quick and easy method for me to extract that to its own `.xib` file so that I do not need to create `.xib` from scratch? Thanks.

Comment: Copy and paste?

Comment: I tried copying the content view of the prototype cell in the storyboard and pasting it onto the .xib, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What exactly happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File -> New -> File... in the Xcode menu and select the "Empty" template from under the "User Interface" section. This creates an empty xib file.

Select the prototype cell from the storyboard, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the cell. Go to the newly created xib file, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the cell.

In your code, you should remember to register the xib file with the table view:

```
tableView.register(
    UINib(nibName: "YourXibFileName", bundle: nil), 
    forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourCellId"
)
```

Now you can delete the cell in the storyboard.